# digest function whose output size <= input size

Tags: java, cryptography

I am dealing with fixed length records, with fixed length fields. Some of these fields are sensitive ... think account number. Let's say the account number in my record is defined as a maximum of 19 bytes. I would like to find (or create) a hash of the account number, the result of which itself is no more than 19 bytes. This way, I can still correlate records by this field, the original value not recoverable, and importantly my fixed length record and field size is not changed. Basically, for any field a, f(a) = a' where sizeof(a) == sizeof(a'). Is this possible, even if not cryptographically secure?

Comment: please show your code or your previous attempt for example add your code to your question etc...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to limit the size of the hash to 19 bytes, you could simply truncate a standard hash. Obviously, this increases the chance of hash collisions (two account numbers hashing to the same value).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784335/how-much-can-you-truncate-a-sha1-hash-and-be-reasonably-sure-of-having-an-unique) which discusses truncation.

However, the original values may be recoverable by brute force. The number of account numbers will probably not be huge, so someone can enumerate them all, run them through the same hashing algorithm, and determine the original account number of a given record. This is a real vulnerability which has been exploited in practice to de-anonymise data.

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer your question directly, but what you are looking for is referred to as "tokenization," I believe. One reason to use tokenization instead of a simple digest or hashing scheme is to avoid problems related to collisions. Some providers even perform this exact type of tokenization for things like replacing a credit card number with a valid (as far as the *format* is concerned) token that can be processed like a regular credit card number without exposing any sensitive information.