# Manipulate CSV files with Powershell (generate column for hashkey)

Tags: powershell, csv, hash, hashmap, hashtable

I have a CSV file with about 10 columns separated with a ; (semicolon). I would like to add another column which generates a hashkey for the first columns value.

Is there a possibility in Powershell to do this? Also are there short haskeys (up to 10 to 15 chars)?

### Example:

Old:

`10000;value2;value3....`

New:

`HashkeyOf10000;1000;value2;value3...`

Comment: `Also are there short hashkeys (up to 10 to 15 chars)` <-- What does this mean?

Comment: For example MD5 is 35 chars long. Just wanted to know if there are any shorter ones.

Comment: Looking at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567089/hash-function-that-produces-short-hashes)(in Python but logic should be the same)they just truncated the result. It allows for possible issues but they should be few and far between.

Comment: Also read this discussion on the topic: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/250235/whats-the-shortest-generating-one-way-hash-algorithm which says that it cant really be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [calculated property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) for adding a column to a CSV:

```
$csv = 'C:\path\to\your.csv'

(Import-Csv $csv -Delimiter ';') |
  select -Property @{n='Hashkey';e={Calc-Hash $_.A}},* |
  Export-Csv $csv -Delimiter ';' -NoType
```

Replace `Calc-Hash` with the actual name of your hash function and `A` with the actual name of the first column of your CSV.

The parentheses around `Import-Csv` are required to ensure that reading the file is completed before writing the output starts.