# Laravel "Hash::make" alternative for url parameters?

Tags: php, laravel

How can I do hashing url paramaters in Laravel? 
I know the Hash::make method, but that's a method for passwords (those hashes are not very url-friendly). 
Does Laravel have a beter alternative, so I can hash parameters like http://url?key=2jd8dka72

Comment: your example url is also not a friendly url?

Comment: yes thats an example url how it has to be. But a Laravel Hash::make() hash is like: %242y%2410%246nROENnpBmwDaxElOMs9402eQIEVBlJTMxjUO6726caxwbbvxNI6m

Comment: so just a short hash?

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567089/hash-function-that-produces-short-hashes

Comment: also, what are your priorities. Cryptographic security? Minimal collisions? Speed?

Comment: i assume zero collisions or its pretty useless

Comment: not only short, but espcially url-friendly (no % chacters). But more a method like the wordpress wp_nonce() method.

Comment: what is the use case?

Comment: An use case: a user can send a mail to another user with an url: 
http://url?send_mail_to_user=15&key=kah38sja
(where 'key' is a hash of 15). In the send_mail() function I can verify the key  and user_id.

Answer (score 8):

you can use Laravel Encrypt function for that .

put 
 `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;`
in header section and than use `Crypt::encrypt($param)` to encrypt param and  `Crypt::decrypt($param)` to decrypt it.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `base64` encoding to make it more friendly looking.

```
use Hash;
...
$id = 15;
$key = base64_encode(Hash::make($id));
echo "http://someurl?send_mail_to_user=$id&key=$key";
```

When you check it:

```
use Hash;
...
$keyDecoded = base64_decode($request->key);
if(Hash::check($request->id, $keyDecoded)) {
   // checked
}
```

Another way is to use some complicated function like a large number at another base. But it is not secured (just security through obscurity):

```
echo base_convert($id * 250 + 5675675, 10, 33); // converts 15 to 4q18q
echo ((base_convert('4q18q', 33, 10) - 5675675) / 250); // converts back, but this one is not being used
// checking:
if(base_convert($request->id * 250 + 5675675, 10, 33) === $request->key) {
   // checked
}
```

Comment: yes I know. But I don't understand why Laravel doesn't have a default function for this. How do other laravel sites hash url parameters?

Comment: As for password reset token, it is generated with `str_random` and stored in another field of an entity, so it is passed as a friendly string: `reset password via link http://site.ru/password/reset/df06d70b6257690941b4130e5b293932cdb47061593aa0716e79987cad71bd78`
You store just an id, password restoring stores two fields: id and token.

Comment: Laravel has encryption class  Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt to do all this for us.

Comment: He needs to pass a friendly looking string and to check it then. I've introduced two ways. Does it really deserve two downs? What's up?

Comment: It is not strictly defined to use crypting. Hashing suits his purposes as well.

Comment: String generated from Crypt are url friendly

Comment: `base_convert` and `base64_encode` too. It's a bad practice, to downvote another answer that does solve the problem just because it differs from yours.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. In my opinion your answer is the best answer for my question, I have not seen any better solutions.