# How to use the Hash facade safely in Laravel 8+ to use the result as a route parameter

Tags: php, hash, routes, laravel-8

I'm trying to hash *some text* and later-on use it as a parameter in a route.

I'm using the **Hash** facade to hash the text like the following

```php
$hash = Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::make($text);
```

Then I'm passing it as param like this

```php
//web.php
Route::get('profile/{$hashedText}/info', [ProfileController::class, 'info'])->name('profile.info');
//index.blade.php
route('profile.info', $hashedText);
```

The problem I'm facing is that Hash::make function doesn't always generate a URL friendly result(ie: existence of '/', '?=', '&'...)

I've noticed that the Hash::make function is not constant (if I run it twice with the same text I get different results) so I think I can loop through results till I get a good result.

Is there a good approach to overcome this?

Comment: Does that answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45759995/laravel-hashmake-alternative-for-url-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do this:

```
$thing = strtr(base64_encode($string), '+/=', '._-');
```

This will base64 encode a string and replace any +, / or = with ., _ or -.

Can obviously add other substitutions.

Could combine it with Laravel hashing lib.

Comment: This was very helpful. Further-more, As Base64 encoded strings may contain only the characters **a-z A-Z 0-9 + / =** and the equal symbol '=' could never be preceded by '?' we can just use ```strtr(base64_encode(Hash::make($text)), '+/', '-_');```

Comment: Yeah, I replaced the = due to a specific API I was sending data to didn't like certain chars, but yeah what suites you're use-case :)