Length of hash generated from standard_hash or dbms_crypto in oracle
I am using below method to generate a hash in oracle:
select STANDARD_HASH(x, 'SHA1'), length(STANDARD_HASH(x, 'SHA1')) from (
    select 'aa' x from dual union all
    select 'bb' x from dual union all
    select 'cc' x from dual
)

As you can see it always generates a RAW data with length as 40.

I need a hash of length RAW(8) instead of RAW(40). Is there any readily available way to do it?
If no, is there a way to generate a hash of length RAW(8) using DBMS_CRYPTO?

You do not have a RAW(40), you have a RAW(20) which when you use LENGTH is implicitly cast to a VARCHAR2(40) with two hexadecimal characters per byte of the original RAW.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567089/hash-function-that-produces-short-hashes

The SHA-1 algorithm always generates a 160-bit (20-byte) hash; you cannot vary the size of it.
You are seeing 40 bytes because you are using LENGTH which expects the first argument to be a string and the RAW is being implicitly converted to a hexadecimal string with two hexadecimal characters per byte which doubles the length.
If you use UTL_RAW.LENGTH to generate the output then you will see the byte length without converting to a string.
If you only want an 8-bytes then you could use UTL_RAW.SUBSTR to take the first 8-bytes of the SHA-1 hash:
SELECT STANDARD_HASH(x, 'SHA1') AS hash,
       UTL_RAW.LENGTH(STANDARD_HASH(x, 'SHA1')) AS len,
       UTL_RAW.SUBSTR(STANDARD_HASH(x, 'SHA1'), 1, 8) AS byte8_hash,
       UTL_RAW.LENGTH(UTL_RAW.SUBSTR(STANDARD_HASH(x, 'SHA1'), 1, 8)) AS byte8_len
FROM   table_name

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (x) AS
  SELECT 'aa' x FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bb' x FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'cc' x FROM DUAL

Outputs:



HASH
LEN
BYTE8_HASH
BYTE8_LEN




0xE0C9035898DD52FC65C41454CEC9C4D2611BFB37
20
0xE0C9035898DD52FC
8


0x9A900F538965A426994E1E90600920AFF0B4E8D2
20
0x9A900F538965A426
8


0xBDB480DE655AA6EC75CA058C849C4FAF3C0F75B1
20
0xBDB480DE655AA6EC
8



(Note: The risk of hash-collisions will be greater with an 8-byte hash compared to a 20-byte hash but, assuming that the original hash function is sufficiently random, truncating a longer hash to 8-bytes should not increase the hash-collisions when compared to directly generating an 8-byte hash.)
fiddle

The actual problem I have is I have store this hash value into a table whose column data type is RAW(8). Hence I was looking for  RAW data with  fixed size of 8. Is it safe to do a substr here? @MT0

@Vijay UTL_RAW.SUBSTR(value, 1, 8) will return a RAW consisting of the first 8 bytes of the value input. If your value input has 8-or-more bytes (and a SHA-1 hash will have 20 bytes) then the output will have exactly 8 bytes (which you can see from the byte8_len column in the answer). You need to use UTL_RAW.SUBSTR and not SUBSTR (as the first works with RAW and the second strings). If that is not what you are asking then you need to qualify what "safe" means.

Apologies.. I was referring to UTL_RAW.SUBSTR when I said SUBSTR
